# Google Analytics referral exclusions not working

Tags: google-analytics

We have two domains, domain.com and subdomain.domain.com, and they both report to the same GA profile.

We have added both domains to the referral exclusions list and they have been added for a few months now.

On one page we redirect users from domain.com to subdomin.domain.com then after they're done back to domain.com. We are seeing domain.com showing up on our referrals with a referral path which matches that first redirect.

How come? Is there a bug with the referral exclusions list which doesn't block all referrals? I heard some people mention the referral exclusion list will only work on new sessions, however we're still getting them even through new sessions. Any ideas?

Edit: Both domains are part of the same root domain

Comment: Do you have cross-domain tracking setup, since you are tracking between two different domains? By the way, this question is best asked in Webmasters, as it is not related to coding.

Comment: @nyuen hey thanks for your response. I messed up the second domain is a sub-domain of the first and they share the cookie data. I've edited my post

Comment: Check the bottom of this page to rule out any of those things which may cause self-referrals: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en